# ¿Porqué modificaciones de un archivo no están tenido en cuenta en el notebook en la misma carpeta?

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo un clase que permite obtener precios de acciones desde una base de datos que no esta puesta al dia y quiero anadir los datos que faltan. Utilicé [Stocker](https://github.com/antoinecomp/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker), una biblioteca para analizar y predecir precios de las acciones. Copié y modifiqué stocker.py en el directorio donde intenté ejecutarlo en Jupyter Notebook pero no parece que mi modificaciones fue tenido en cuenta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porqué mis modificaciones no estan tenido en cuenta en el notebook ?

Ahora estoy verificando si lo tienen en cuenta en la linea de comando. Pero tengo problemas para descargar las librerias que ya estan en Anaconda.

#### Siguiendo los consejos de Abulafia

El PATH esta :

```
['', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\antoi\\.ipython',
'C:\\Users\\antoi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpnlvgnv43',
'C:\\Users\\antoi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp1ix0gmc0']
```

Comment: Tras modificar el código de un módulo tienes que reiniciar el kernel del notebook, pues el `import` sólo se hace la primera vez aunque ejecutes más veces la celda. Por otro lado, es posible que la versión modificada que has puesto no esté en la ruta donde Jupyter busca. Puedes obtener esta ruta si ejecutas en una celda `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias para estos detalles. Sin embargo, a pesar del hecho de que estoy importando Stocker, no veo nada relativo en el PATH.

Comment: Obviamente en una de las rutas que muestras, ha de haber una carpeta llamada `stocker` o bien un fichero llamado `stocker.py`. Posiblemente en  `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages`. Las carpetas finales con nombres temporales posiblemente son creadas cuando el notebook arranca y sean diferentes en cada ejecución

Comment: @abulafia haa, no. Puesto `stocker.py` directamente en el directorio que podemos ver en la captura de pantalla : `C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance\prediction`

Comment: Es por decir en la misma carpeta que `stocker_modified.ipynb`. Pensaba que seria suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces un `import` en python, el módulo en cuestión se busca sólo en las carpetas especificadas en `sys.path`.

Poner el módulo en la misma carpeta que el `.ipynb` no suele funcionar, porque cuando lanzas Jupyter la "carpeta por defecto" desde la que jupyter ha arrancado no es necesariamente la misma carpeta en la que estaba el `.ipynb`.

Lo siguiente es un "hack" (no muy recomendable, pero bueno), que averigua en qué carpeta está el notebook cuya celda se está ejecutando, y añade esa carpeta en primer lugar a `sys.path`, por lo que los `import` que hagas después buscarían primero en esa carpeta.

```
import os, sys, inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
sys.path.insert(0, currentdir)
```

Recuerda además reiniciar el *kernel* del notebook si ya habías importado antes el módulo `stocker`, pues los `import` *cachean* los módulos importados y un `import` posterior no releería del disco los cambios realizados.

Si andas haciendo modificaciones frecuentes en `stocker.py`, puede resultar tedioso reiniciar el kernel tras cada modificación. Puedes usar este otro "hack" para forzar a python a que recargue el módulo:

```
import imp
import stocker
imp.reload(stocker)
```

si pones ese código en una celda, cada vez que re-ejecutes la celda, se cargará de nuevo el módulo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! De acuerdo, si no es recomendable pero hago muchos cambios en este archivo, ¿cuál es el procedimiento a seguir?

Comment: @ThePassenger Lo que te indico al final de la respuesta. Haces una celda con lo de `import imp` etc y re-ejecutas esa celda cada vez que hagas cambios en `stocker.py`.

Comment: Haa, gracias. No fui seguro si tenia que hacer las primeras comandos

Comment: @ThePassenger Sí, los primeros comandos son necesarios para decirle a Python en qué carpeta está `stocker.py`, y los segundos para recargar el módulo cada vez que lo cambies.

Comment: Ha ! Me sorprende porque solo he puesto imp.reload y llama al archivo que modifiqué

Comment: @ThePassenger Eso es que seguramente ya tenías ejecutados los otros comandos en ese kernel, o que el `sys.path` ya incluía la carpeta correcta, o que habías lanzado el notebook desde línea de comandos, y desde la carpeta correcta.